# Signature Scanning explanation

Tags: c++, reverse-engineering

I've recently started learning reverse-engineering, and I suddenly came across signature scanning.

```
DWORD FindPattern(char *szPattern, char *szMask)
{
    // Get the current process information
    MODULEINFO mInfo = {0};
    GetModuleInformation(GetCurrentProcess(), GetModuleHandle(NULL), &mInfo, sizeof(MODULEINFO));
    // Find the base address 
    DWORD dwBase = (DWORD)mInfo.lpBaseOfDll;
    DWORD dwSize =  (DWORD)mInfo.SizeOfImage;
    // Get the pattern length
    DWORD dwPatternLength = (DWORD)strlen(szMask);
    // Loop through all the process
    for(DWORD i = 0; i < dwSize - dwPatternLength; i++)
    {
        bool bFound = true;
        // Loop through the pattern caracters
        for (DWORD j = 0; j < dwPatternLength; j++)
            bFound &= szMask[j] == '?' || szPattern[j] == *(char*)(dwBase + i + j);

        // If found return the current address
        if(bFound) 
            return dwBase + i;
    }
    // Return null
    return NULL;
}
```

I want to know:

1. What exactly this function do?
2. Where it should be used?
3. What's the working principle of this function/method?
4. What and why shall we pass to "char *szPattern"?

Comment: Why don't you TRY to answer your questions, and we'll tell you if you are right. You'll learn so much more that way...

Comment: @MatsPetersson okay, as you say.
Answers:(all answers listed below are my guesses)
1. finds out memory address for a specific function.
2. knowing address for a function
3. I can't have a guess on it at all
4. same as above

Answer (score 1):

First, look at the code forgetting about all the module stuff. If you look closely you can see that the nested for loop is basically a (fairly inefficient) substring search. It searches for the given szPattern as a substring in a specific memory region. szMask is an extension of the pattern, so you can search with "wildcards".

The `GetModuleInformation` part just gets the memory region of the main executable module, so you can search for a binary string in your executable. *It is quite funny if you compile it into your program, `FindPattern` invocations will most likely find their own constants in the binary*

So what is this thing used for? You can search for parts of well-known functions by their machine code, so you dont have to hardcode function base addresses. You even can use wildcards to mask out changing parts like concrete variable or function reference addresses.

Answer (score 1):

I think this question deserves a practical example for explanation.

The purpose of signature scanning is to locate a sequence of instructions or data in memory that may change location when software is patched. It is impractical to hard-code these values and constantly push out a new version of your software whenever the software you are modifying changes.

#### The following code illustrates this:

```
uint8_t mask [] = { 0xff, 0xff, 0xff,            // cmp     [ebx+28h], eax
                    0,    0,                     // jz      short <...>
                    0xff, 0xff, 0xff,            // cmp     eax, 2
                    0,    0,                     // jl      short <...>
                    0xff, 0,    0,     0, 0,     // mov     <tickaddr>,  eax
                    0xff, 0,    0,     0, 0,     // mov     <tickaddr2>, eax
                    0xff, 0xff, 0xff             // mov     [ebx+28h],   eax
                  };

uint8_t sig [] = { 0x39, 0x43, 0x28,             // cmp     [ebx+28h], eax
                   0x74, 0x12,                   // jz      short <...>
                   0x83, 0xF8, 0x02,             // cmp     eax, 2
                   0x7C, 0x0D,                   // jl      short <...>
                   0xA3, 0x64, 0xB4, 0x17, 0x02, // mov     <tickaddr>,  eax
                   0xA3, 0x68, 0xB4, 0x17, 0x02, // mov     <tickaddr2>, eax
                   0x89, 0x43, 0x28              // mov     [ebx+28h],   eax
                  };

if (*((DWORD *)config.framerate.speedresetcode2_addr) != 0x0F8831274) {
  uintptr_t addr = (uintptr_t)TZF_Scan (sig, 23, mask);

  if (addr != NULL) {
    config.framerate.speedresetcode2_addr = addr + 3;

    dll_log.Log (L"Scanned SpeedResetCode2 Address: %06Xh", addr + 3);

    TICK_ADDR_BASE = *(DWORD *)((uint8_t *)(addr + 11));

    dll_log.Log (L" >> TICK_ADDR_BASE: %06Xh", TICK_ADDR_BASE);
  }
  else {
    dll_log.Log (L" >> ERROR: Unable to find SpeedResetCode2 memory!");
  }
}
```

Here, I have determined the code in question follows a certain pattern and the mask is developed to ignore memory addresses and jump labels that are going to frequently change. I ***DO*** want those memory addresses and jump labels, but as far as the function signature goes, they have to be ignored because they are not constant. I treat these "DONTCARE" bytes using **0x00** in the mask to ignore them during pattern matching.

Additionally, I have actually written the address to a config file. The scanning only occurs on startup when the stored address no longer matches expected values (**0x0F8831274**). This is because signature scanning can be an inefficient process - done once or twice per-program it's fine, but my software has to locate and patch several functions. So caching the located addresses is an important optimization strategy.

---

There is a flaw in the implementation of the scanner in your original question that needs to be addressed. In real-world software, you will run into regions of process memory that are not committed and / or inaccessible. If you were to naively scan the entire image's memory space you would very likely generate access violation exceptions and crash the program you are trying to modify.

Calling [`VirtualQuery (...)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366902(v=vs.85).aspx) is necessary to ensure this problem is avoided. I will point you to the [implementation of `TZF_Scan (...)`](https://github.com/Kaldaien/TZF/blob/master/tzf_dsound/scanner.cpp#L28) to illustrate how this can be used.